# jQuery UI 1.10.3 Dialog Box, dragging moves away dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jQuery 1.10.1 with migrate, jQueryUI 1.10.3, jQueryValidate 1.11.1.

Just using a simple form, it has two fields. On submit if values are not provided then a dialog box is displayed with a message.

**Issue:** In IE 10 When user tries to move (drag) the error message dialog box it just moves down. This only happens when vertical scroll bar is appears in the browser window. 
Verified in Chrome 27 it works. Sometimes gives the same issue in Firefox 21 and Opera 12.15.

**Note:** It works fine with jQuery UI 1.10.2 only issue is there in 1.10.3.

Sample Source

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .label {width:100px;text-align:right;float:left;padding-right:10px;font-weight:bold;}
        .label1 {width:350px; text-align:right; padding-top:300px;padding-bottom:30px; font-weight:bold;  }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> 

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#register-form").validate({
            rules: { firstname: "required", lastname: "required" },
            messages: { firstname: "Need First Name", lastname: "Need Last Name" },
            showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
                        $("#diverror").dialog({ modal: true });
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" id="register-form">
        <div class="label">First Name</div><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /><br />
        <div class="label">Last Name</div><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /><br />

        <div class="label1">Making page to scroll. Scroll down to submit</div>
        <div class="label1">Making page to scroll. Scroll down to submit</div>
        <div class="label1">Making page to scroll. Scroll down to submit</div>

        <div style="margin-left:140px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
  </form>
    <div id="diverror" title="Basic dialog"><p>This is the default DIVERROR which is useful for displaying information.</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: damn i lost 2 hours now , same issue , getting the issue in chrome !!!

Comment: This issue was fixed in **jQuery UI 1.10.4**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verified jQuery UI website, its a bug in jQuery UI.

Ticket# 9354: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9354

Ticket# 9315: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9315

Comment: I just spent the last 3 hours debugging my code. I had assumed it was something in my own code that was causing a conflict. Wish I had found this question when I first searched 3 hours ago.

Comment: This was my issue in Firefox and Chrome as well. They released 1.10.4 recently and that seems to fix the issue.

Comment: This problem still occurs in later versions of IE. According to [this](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9315#comment:53) comment it's to be fixed in 1.11.0